# Chern class map and the exponential sequence

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, hodge-theory, algebraic-cycles, chow-groups

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over the complex numbers, and

$$c^1_X : \text{NS}(X)\to H^2_{\rm Betti}(X,\mathbf{Z}(1))$$

the first cycle map to Betti cohomology. The cokernel $\text{coker}(c^1_X)$ sits inside the coherent cohomology $H^2(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$, which is seen using the exponential sequence

$$0\to\mathbf{Z}(1)\to\mathcal{O}_X\to\mathcal{O}_X^{\times}\to 1$$

Is the same true for higher codimension cycle maps? That is:

> **Question.** For $r\ge 1$ an integer, let
>
> $$c^r_X : A^r_{\rm hom}(X)\to H^{2r}_{\rm Betti}(X,\mathbf{Z}(r))$$
>
> be the $r$-th cycle map, with $A^r_{\rm hom}(X)$ the Chow group of cycles modulo homological equivalence. Is $\text{coker}(c^r_X)$ contained in some coherent cohomology group? (eg. $H^{2r}(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$?)

Is there some "higher exponential sequence" that can be used to see this?

Comment: The cokernel of $c^r_X$ often has nonzero torsion for $r\geq 2$, cf. Koll\'ar's "Trento examples".  Every cohomology group of a coherent sheaf on a complex scheme is a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space, and thus it is a torsion-free Abelian group.

Comment: @JasonStarr I agree. However, could you please tell me if I'm missing something: it looks to me that, under the Hodge conjecture, the answer to my question is yes *up to finite torsion*. Indeed, we consider the exact sequence $$J^{r,r}(X)\to H^{2r}_{\mathcal{D}}(X,\mathbf{Z}(r))\to H^{2r}_{\rm Betti}(X,\mathbf{Z}(r))\to H^{2r}(X)/F^rH^{2r}(X)\to \cdots$$
and the image of the second map is $\text{Hdg}^r(X)$, which up to finite torsion is $c^r_X(A^r_{\rm hom}(X))$ under the HC. So indeed the cokernel of $c^r_X$ injects into a coherent cohom gp, $H^{2r}(X)/F^rH^{2r}(X)$, up to finite torsion.

Comment: Above, $H^*_{\mathcal{D}}(X)$ is Deligne cohomology, $H^*(X)$ is $H^*_{\rm Betti}(X,\mathbf{C})$, $H^r(X)/F^rH^r(X)$ is a sum of coherent cohomology groups by Hodge theory.

Comment: I might be wrong but for $r=1$, by the $(1,1)$ theorem the map $c^r_X$ lands in $H^{1,1} \cap H^2(X,\mathbf{Z})$. So I'm guessing for higher $r$ we have that $c^r_X$ lands in $H^{r,r} \cap H^{2r}(X,\mathbf{Z}(r))$?